# How to split a string after specific character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have followed problem: I have one column, which contains a lot of strings. Something like this:

```
"Shop/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung"
```

The first two words are always different. This could be for example

```
"HTML-Title/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung"
```

or

```
"Info/Template/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung“  
"tpl_landingpage/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung“ etc.
```

From this string, I want to have only first two wards! 
Example: 
Original text:

```
„Shop/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung“
```

I want to keep: `Shop/Kaufprozess`

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Shop/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung'
SELECT SUBSTRING (@,1, CHARINDEX('/',@, CHARINDEX('/',@,0)+1) - 1 )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    --------------------
    Shop/Kaufprozess

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DECLARE @DataGet TABLE (id INT IDENTITY,String varchar(300))

INSERT INTO @DataGet
SELECT 'Shop/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Info/Template/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'tpl_landingpage/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung'


;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT 1                      AS Seq, 
                id, 
                CHARINDEX('/', string) AS Pos, 
                string 
         FROM   @DataGet 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT seq + 1, 
                id, 
                CHARINDEX('/', string, pos + 1) AS Pos, 
                string 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  pos > 0 
                AND seq <= 2) 
SELECT string,SUBSTRING(string, 0, pos)AS ReqString 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER () 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY id 
                   ORDER BY seq ) AS Dup 
        FROM   cte 
        WHERE  pos > 0)dt 
WHERE  dup = 2 
ORDER  BY dt.id, 
          dt.dup ASC
```

Result

```
String                                                  ReqString
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shop/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung              Shop/Kaufprozess
Info/Template/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung                 Info/Template
tpl_landingpage/Kaufprozess/Zahlungsart u. Zustellung   tpl_landingpage/Kaufprozess
```